# How to rename a "using Directive" C#

Tags: c#, excel

How would you rename a "Using Directive" Using C#?

Because some times You copy a class from somewhere (Example below)

```
//Other Code
        Excel.ApplicationClass excel;
        Excel.Workbooks workbooks;
        Excel.Workbook workbook;
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
        Excel.Sheets worksheets;
//Other Code
```

and instead of renaming everything to

```
//Other Code
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass excel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks workbooks;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets worksheets;
//Other Code
```

So having something like

```
Using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass as 'Excel'
```

Comment: How about if you use 'using i = Microsoft.Office.Interop' and the variables can be changed 'i.Excel.ApplicationClass excel;'

Comment: That "how to change namespace of entire project?" isn't even close to what I asked for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create an alias like this:

```
// for whole namespace
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
// use like this
Excel.ApplicationClass excel = /* ... */;

// or for single type
using ExcelApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass;
// use like this
ExcelApp excel = /* ... */;
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you're just looking for:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

(I don't *think* you wanted `ApplicationClass` here. That would be an alias for the *type* rather than the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace. It's not really clear from your question though.)

This is called a *using-alias-directive*. From section 9.4.1 of the C# 4 spec:

> A *using-alias-directive* introduces an identifier that serves as an alias for a namespace or type within the immediately enclosing compilation unit or namespace body.

So after that `using` directive, it *would* be valid to have:

```
Excel.ApplicationClass excel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
```

... which is what I *think* you wanted?

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the msdn documentation says http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

```
using [alias = ]class_or_namespace;
```

So in your case:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```